# JavaScript removing contents of form hidden by animatedcollapse.hide

Tags: javascript, forms, cgi

I'm using JavaScript to hide and show div contents within a simple web form I made.

However, I noticed that the submitted form (it sends the form as a dictionary to Python CGI) may still contain nonempty submitted values for hidden items. Usually, this happens because you enter some values into field X, click a link that hides the div containing field X, and then submit.

I know that I can manually clear all of the input fields (i.e. field X, etc.) in a div when the div is hidden, but is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want something elegant, you could look into jQuery, and remove all hidden elements before submitting like `$("#form :hidden").remove()`.

Comment: +1 So would adding `onSubmit="$(\"#form :hidden\").remove()"` to my form declaration be sufficient? If so, you should repost as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery, you can make DOM manipulation both easy and elegant.

For your needs, you can remove hidden input elements before submitting: http://jsfiddle.net/tTzn2/.

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).find(":hidden").remove(); // hide hidden elements before submitting
});
```

Comment: Sorry-- where do I put this code? I tried putting it inside `<head>` in its own `<script type="text/javascript">` declaration, but I still see my hidden values go through; perhaps I made a mistake?

Comment: @Oliver: I'm not sure how experienced you are with jQuery, but usually this goes into a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` block. Also make sure you actually include jQuery with a `<script src="...">` tag.

Comment: +1 Perfect! I've now convinced Django that I'm committing a cross site request forgery, but it works with CSRF turned off. Now to convince Django that this is OK...