# CSRF error in Django after removal of hidden fields

Tags: javascript, django, forms, csrf

I got some [good advice on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745191/javascript-removing-contents-of-form-hidden-by-animatedcollapse-hide) about how to remove all hidden fields using JavaScript.

Submitting the form sends the user to `/submit`, calling the `submit_form` view. In my views.py file, I define my index page (with the form), and the page that receives the submission (my `/index` page prints errors for me, but that shouldn't influence anything):

```
def index(request, error_message = ''):
    t = get_template('index.html')
    html = t.render(Context( { 'ERROR_MESSAGE': error_message } ))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def submit_form(request):
    # get the POST data out of request and do something
    pass
```

I've been able to suppress the error by changing the code to:

```
from django.contrib.csrf.middleware import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def submit_form(request):
    # get the POST data out of request and do something
    pass
```

This essentially turns off CSRF for the submit_form function. However, I'm sure this is not the ideal fix (now I'm not checking for forgeries in my form).

I tried more sophisticated fixes, like

- Adding [this code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) to immediately follow the jQuery code (which removes hidden fields from submission)

```
init:function(){
var ac=this

    # advice from StackOverflow to remove hidden 
    # fields from POST submission

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("form").submit(function() {
        $(this).find(":hidden").remove();
    });

# AJAX CSRF code inserted here
    #...
}
```

- [Adding `{% csrf_token %}` immediately after my form declaration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/). I also tried adding code to my `index` view to send the `csrf_token` to `index`; that made the token viewable in the rendered index.html source (which I gathered was a bad idea).

I've seen several questions asking about things like this (and references in the Django book), but haven't seen a simple and clear answer. For instance-- even if I was going to tolerate publishing my `csrf_token` (which, still I know is a bad idea), it is still unclear whether I should render that in my index page (and then it will submitted form will have the token) or whether I am supposed to do something in my `submit_form` code. The Django code book (linked above) uses `my_view` as the view function where the token is rendered; this name is not very helpful!

Does anyone have a small example with CSRF working (with javascript modifying the form)? I really think it would be useful (to me and to lots of other people on StackOverflow to see this. Ideally, it would be as simple as possible (two views: one delivers the form, the other prints its contents).

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

*Update:* I still get this error, even when I [prefent the `csrfmiddlewaretoken`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871388/javascript-to-remove-all-hidden-elements-but-one) from being removed. When I *do not do any JavaScript processing, my form is fine. And I've verified that only my

Is there some way that CSRF can see that some form elements are removed? I can't find anything different in my `QueryDict` object (that sends the data from the form using POST).

I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you remove the hidden CSRF-field and the solution is to not remove this field, you could probably do that with the jQuery selector to have it ignore that field with :not(input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]).

Btw, Django doesn't have a problem with unknown field names sent to the form-class, it will happily ignore them so the removal of the hidden fields tradeoff is very small.