# JavaScript to remove all hidden elements but one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Someone helped me find JavaScript [code to remove hidden form fields from submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745191/javascript-removing-contents-of-form-hidden-by-animatedcollapse-hide) and [code that ignores a certain field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747209/csrf-error-in-django-after-removal-of-hidden-fields/7747430#7747430) that I don't want removed (whether it's hidden or not):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
$(this).find(":hidden").remove(); // hide hidden elements before submitting
});
```

and

```
:not(input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken])
```

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to put these together. I'm sure it's a basic JavaScript question, but I can't seem to piece these together.

Does anyone know how to remove all hidden form entries *not named* `csrfmiddlewaretoken`? If you do, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(this).find(":hidden").not('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').remove();
```

Or

```
$(this).find(":hidden").filter(':not(input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken])').remove();
```

Or

```
$(this).find("input[name!=csrfmiddlewaretoken]:hidden").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).find(":hidden").filter("[name!='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `this` as a context argument, which will be potentially faster than making a jQuery object from it. The `:not()` expression can follow the `:hidden` without spaces, meaning that it adds a second condition to the `:hidden` selector.

```
$(":hidden:not(input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken])", this).remove();
```